# find all letters without repeating regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

help me please to find all letters in string without repeating using regex JS.

**Examples:**

```js
let str = "abczacg";
str = str.match(/ pattern /); // return has to be: abczg

str = "aabbccdd" //return:abcd.

str = "hello world"//return: helo wrd
```

**Is it possible?**

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a regexp. A regexp match is always a contiguous substring of the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach.  We can first reverse the input string.  Then, do a global regex replacement on the following pattern:

```regex
(\w)(?=.*\1)
```

This will strip off any character for which we can find the same character later in the string.  But, as we will be running this replacement on the *reversed* string, this has the actual effect of removing all duplicate letters other than their first occurrence.  Finally, we reverse the remaining string again to arrive at the expected output.

```js
var input = "abczacg";
var output = input.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\w)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
output = output.split("").reverse().join("");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Clever :) Is `str.split('').reverse().join('')` really the idiomatic way to reverse a string in JS?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without using a regex using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
[
  "abczacg",
  "aabbccdd",
  "hello world"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log([...new Set(s.split(''))].join(''))
})
```

Comment: Fourth Bird: Your answer may viable, but it assumes that a JavaScript `Set` maintains the original ordering of letters.  In many languages, this would not be the case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, good point. I can find that a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#description) keeps the insertion order. If I'm interpreting this correctly, when passing an array to the [Set constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-set-iterable) it will call `add` for every item.

Comment: Then this is a good approach +1, maybe more performant than mine.